What would a be a common terms for lower body garments that have only a single opening?
For example, kilt, skirt, dress. India has a lot of them: sari, dhoti, mundu etc. Basically a bottom garment that doesn't join between the legs. Maybe even a poncho without any bottoms, or a kurta without pajamas, a kameez without the salwar. I'm trying to figure out the term for single opening on the bottom of a lower body garment. Hope I explained it clearly enough.

A skirt is the more general term, applying not just to clothing (where it is a garment with no top). But it is unclear whether you want the name of a garment, or a term for the opening at the bottom. Many of the words you cite are words from a local language: poncho, sari, pyjamas, dhoti etc. And a sari has no openings.

Garments that do join between the legs are technically described as bifurcated, so you could call them 'non-bifurcated garments'. But aren't a sari and a dhoti just pieces of cloth draped round the body in particular ways?

"Open between the legs" would be descriptive. "Skirt" is used for the garment below the waist, including the bottom part of a dress. You should give a specific sentence you want to use the word in, otherwise this is a question about making clothes and belongs on crafts SE.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169656/44619

Cambridge dictionary s image of dhoti is called mundu in South India.  The term "single opening" is not clear. Are you looking for unstitched piece of clothing - like mundu, lungi, dhoti? You also mentioned Kurta, kameez which are stitched garments.

OP is looking for a generic term for lower body garment. Kameez and kurta are mentioned as Kate Bunting commented to explain 'non-bifurcated garments

@JamesMathai I agree with dhoti, and I completely disagree with bifurcated garment.

@Lambie The word bifurcated is there. Non-bifurcated is suggested by Kate Bunting.

I’m voting to close this question because it is conflicted and unclear, talking about "lower body garments" but naming several upper body garments.

Non-bifurcated garment = garment that is not bifurcated.
As OP is looking for a generic term for a garment without bifurcation (worn below the waist) I am suggesting the word given by Kate Bunting in the comments. Non-bifurcated garment.. Other words to describe it include the native words used in places where such garments are worn. These words have been accepted into the English language - dhoti, lungi, kilts, skirt.

A bifurcated garment is an undergarment thdat is divided into two sections, worn by both men and women with variations in length. Types of bifurcated garments include trousers and shorts, where the primary distinction lies in their length
https://www.fibre2fashion.com/industry-article/5690/constructing-a-bifurcated-garment-trousers-and-shorts#:~:text=A%20bifurcated%20garment%20is%20an,distinction%20lies%20in%20their%20length.

You could find many words from Indian languages in English - pundit, guru, mango, coir, etc.
Similarly "dhoti" and "lungi" are also there in English. "Kilt" is worn in Scotland. As these aren't common Western wear, the local names are now part of the English language. (Attached image from dictionary.cambridge.org.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
1.dhoti.
noun [ C ].
a loose piece of clothing wrapped around the lower half of the body, worn by some men from South Asia


"Lungi" meaning in dictionaries:

2.lungi.
noun [ C ]
a piece of clothing consisting of a piece of cloth wrapped around the waist and worn by men and women from South Asia.


Collins dictionary
lungi.
in British English.
or lungee (ˈlʊŋɡiː IPA Pronunciation Guide).
noun.
a long piece of cotton cloth worn as a loincloth, sash, or turban by Indian men or as a skirt


You certainly find English words drawn from other languages. From your list I would say pundit and guru are good examples. I'm not sure dhoti is (yet) in the same category. It's certainly not a word I would use.

That's not my point. I'm sure you are right that if an English speaker used the word dhoti it would mean what you say. But your own definition specifically references "men from South Asia". In other words, I think of the word as describing Indian clothing, not clothing in general. Therefore it's not the best answer to the OP. I contrast that with guru, which these days means a wise man generally, as well as its original meaning of an Indian spiritual guide.

@PeterKirkpatrick I am not sure if anyone in the west wears a dhoti or a lungi. Only "kilts" which is the national dress of Scotland. The same names used in the country of origin is accepted in English. Some words have been given a different meaning like "pundit". I am deleting my earlier comment.

Nothing wrong with loanwords.

This answer is a bit unclear.  The question is seeking a generic word that can be used to describe a skirt, kilt, dress, dhoti, sari, mundu and any other garment that covers the legs and is tube-shaped.  Are you suggesting that English speakers use the terms dhoti and lungi to refer to skirts, kilts, etc?

@Juhasz "Iskcon" followers who wear it would use the same word (dhoti).It can't be called a "kilt" or a "skirt". When these dresses become a fashion in the west, maybe it would be used commonly. Italian dishes "Pasta" and "Pizza" are known by their original names.

@JamesMathai, I never intended to be critical of you. If you go back to my first comment, that's why I included the bracketed word yet. Who knows where the English language will go in the next 100 years...?

Downvoting because the OP is looking for a generic term equally applicable to a poncho.

@AndyBonner Is poncho a lower body garment or a bottom garment?

@JamesMathai It's a garment worn on the torso that extends beyond the waist; same is true of "kurta without pajamas [or] a kameez without the salwar," and the OP is looking for something that applies equally to all these. They said "lower body garment" but these start at the neck, and simply extend to the lower body as well.

@AndyBonner OP is looking for a generic term for lower body garment. Kameez and kurta are mentioned as Kate Bunting commented to explain  'non-bifurcated garments

Removing my downvote as edits since then have made this answer more universal. I don't know, however, that "non-bifurcated garment" is a useful phrase that would be readily understood, so I stand by my answer that there is no clear solution short of simply explaining the intended concept.

I found non-bifurcated in various websites. Kilts are knee-length, non-bifurcated pleated tartan skirts, traditionally worn by men in regions like Ireland and Scotland
https://help.scottishkiltshop.com/hc/en-us/articles/208052949-What-is-Difference-Between-Skirt-Kilt

If you say tartan skirt, you needn't say non-bifurcated.

Not every concept has a word. You've noticed a common feature shared by many different garments, but it doesn't have a single name. Other phenomena might—berets, motorcycle helmets, and tiaras are all "headwear." But there's no special word for "a garment that extends below the crotch but doesn't join between the legs."
It's usually best to use specific terms anyway. The only reason to try to find general, "blanket" terms is when our needs are general and vague. For instance, there are many types of footwear that don't cover one's toes, and they wouldn't meet the safety requirements of some places, so they say "no open-toed shoes."

I don't think there is such a word in English.
The best option is to call the garment by its foreign name, even though it might not be recognized by people unfamiliar with the culture. For example, kilt is pretty common, and Sarong is even familiar to a lot of people.
If you can't be specific, the best generic term is either a skirt or a wrap.
Skirt is very gender-specific, however. So if you were describing something a man would wear, you might have to call it a "man-skirt" or something like that.
